# java Stack homework put number on stack

Tags: java, stack

Hello eveyone in need help to answer about question in java stack

This is my question:
Complete the method below that evaluates a string representing an arithmetic expression in reverse Polish (postfix) notation. The string contains an expression consisting of numbers '0' to '9' and operators '+', '-', '*' and '/'.

For example, these are some possible input strings and the corresponding results:

Input:         Output:
        "12+"             3
        "43*"            12
        "123+*"           5

        "123*+"           7
        "12+3*"           9
To help you solve this problem, you can use the standard class Stack which implements a stack of integers:

```
Stack<Integer> stk = new Stack<>(); // create a stack
stk.push(5);                        // push an integer onto the top of the stack
int n = stk.pop();                  // pop an integer from the top of the stack
if ( stk.empty() ) ...              // test if the stack is empty
```

I started to answer this is my code:

```
    Stack<Integer> stk = new Stack<>();

int res=0;

        for (int i = 0; i < expression.length(); i++) {
            char ch = expression.charAt(i);

            if (Character.isDigit(ch)) {
                stk.push(ch - '0');
            } 
else {
                if(stk.isEmpty())
            {
                return 0;
            }

                if (ch == '-') {
                    res = stk.pop() - stk.pop();
                    res=res*-1;
                }

                if (ch == '*') {
                    res = stk.pop() * stk.pop();
                }


                if (ch == '+') {
                    res = stk.pop() + stk.pop();
                }
                if (ch == '/') {
                    res = stk.pop() / stk.pop();
                }
            }

}


     return res;
```

This is error that i recived, i don't understand what is not ok in this code.

error:

```
 An exception of type java.util.EmptyStackException was reported when executing this line:

    res = stk.pop() * stk.pop();

Exception in thread "main" java.util.EmptyStackException
    at java.util.Stack.peek(Stack.java:102)
    at java.util.Stack.pop(Stack.java:84)
    at Main.evaluate(Main.java:28)
    at Main.exitTest(Main.java:78)
    at Main.main(Main.java:104)
```

i need your help thanks for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

To check if the stack is empty, use stk.isEmpty().

For a computation, pop two items from the stack, do the computation on them, and push it on the stack. For example a multiplication:

```
if (ch == '*') {
    stk.push(stk.pop() * stk.pop());
}
```

Comment: yeah this exactly what i doing, and this is not working.

Comment: What do you mean by not working? If you're getting errors, include them in the question

Comment: you have to push the result of the computation on the stack, you're not doing that